# How can I achieve each monitor having its own separate workspace? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces

Folks, I've done some search on the internet but couldn't find a simple solution for this issue. Currently I'm using a notebook connected to a separate monitor. I wanted to have a different workspace for each screen, so that the number of windows is more maintainable and I don't get overwhelmed by it while I'm alt-tabing.

Better illustrating: let's say I want to run VSCode and Google Chrome on Screen 1(workspace 1), etc; and Spotify, VSCode for virtual servers and other non-urgent windows on Screen 2 (workspace 2), so that they won't appear in screen 1 and won't bother me.

How that can be achieved? Do I need a new WM other than Ubuntu's 20.04 gdm3? If so, are there any wm packages with easy GUI for configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong approach (probably) workspaces are inside a DE (and 2 monitors I would assume you want workspaces on EACH of the monitors. What you want is called multi-head, multi-screen, multi-display or multi-monitor (depending on what the "multi" is); those create actual different screens (often independent of eachother) where you share mouse and keyboard.

Comment: ... but wayland ... does not seem to be capable of doing it so yes you might want a diff. system.

Comment: Thanks for your time and interest, @Rinzwind, I've found an extension that pretty much takes care of the problem. It is just a simple workaround, which allows me to alt-tab only the windows in my current monitor: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3148/alt-tab-for-dual-monitor/